# FreeRadius server not responding to Access-Request

Tags: freeradius

I currently deployed freeradius and radtest looks good for local host but when I sent Access-Request from external server, FreeRadius server doesn't reply. see below output of radsniff

```
[root@pgw-radius tmp]# radsniff -i ens192
2023-03-18 17:29:17.588990 (1) Access-Request Id 91 ens192:10.0.34.13:48791 -> 10.0.33.108:1812 +0.000
2023-03-18 17:29:22.788990 (1) ** norsp ** Access-Request Id 91 ens192:10.0.34.13:48791 -> 10.0.33.108:1812
2023-03-18 17:29:52.771149 (2) Access-Request Id 51 ens192:10.0.34.13:48799 -> 10.0.33.108:1812 +35.182
2023-03-18 17:29:52.865949 (3) Access-Request Id 92 ens192:10.0.34.13:48791 -> 10.0.33.108:1812 +35.276
2023-03-18 17:29:57.971149 (2) ** norsp ** Access-Request Id 51 ens192:10.0.34.13:48799 -> 10.0.33.108:1812
2023-03-18 17:29:58.659490 (3) ** norsp ** Access-Request Id 92 ens192:10.0.34.13:48791 -> 10.0.33.108:1812
```

Debug Results

```
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 43265
Listening on proxy address :: port 40852
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 10.0.34.13 port 48791 proto udp
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 10.0.34.13 port 48791 proto udp
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 10.0.34.13 port 48791 proto udp
Ready to process requests
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 10.0.34.13 port 48799 proto udp
Ready to process requests
```

Comment: Have you check if a firewall rules are blocking incomign traffic to port 1812

Comment: Did you add your client's ip/network address to clients.conf? Does the secret match?

Comment: Yes, they match, the secrets are same , I also changed this line in the clients.conf file  #  not be used in any real environment.
        #
        secret = kjhefoihjeqwrfiuh

        #
        #  Old-style clients do not send a Message-Authenticator

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things you can do, first check if `port` 1812 is not blocked by something, also your `Freeradius` could be misconfigured, check the config files `/etc/raddb/clients.conf` and `/etc/raddb/users` be sure that the external server is allowed to send `Acces-Request` packets and the auth method is configured as you want

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the issue was on the **/etc/raddb/users** "Authorize" file, the Server is responding with Access-reject now, the next steps is to check the Authentication and encryption type.